# Spring Boot start the application with configurations check

Tags: spring-boot, lombok

It is about a `Spring Boot` application. I would like to check and inform the user at the beginning if someone configured false the `Yaml file`. I would like to ask some of you,

1. is this the right way to implement it?
2. is the `RuntimeException` the correct choice?
3. did I use the `lombok` annotation correctly?

Thank you

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationProperties{

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class Something {
        private String name;

        @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        private int width;

        @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        private int height;

        public void setWidth(int width) throws Throwable {
            if (0 > width || 100 < width) {
                throw new RuntimeException("The width should be between 0 and 100.");
            }
            this.width = width;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) throws Throwable {
            if (0 > height || 250 < height) {
                throw new RuntimeException("The height should be between 0 and 250.");
            }
            this.height = height;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, welcome to SO! Let me explain how you can validate the application properties. There is an easy way how to achieve this using the validation annotations. The `@ConfigurationProperties` support JSR-303 bean validation:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("prefix")
public class MyProperties {

    @Max(100)
    @Min(0)
    private Integer width;

    @Max(100)
    @Min(1)
    private Integer height;
}
```

Please, note, that this approach will fail the application start if the validation throws an exception.

Secondly, to understand whether this is the right way to do it, you would have to describe your use case. I would personally stick to existing standards and use the validation annotations flow.

Lastly, as for your `lombok` annotations. You can use `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations either globally or place them like this on your fields to specify fine-grained access.

I am not a big fan of the `@Data` annotation since it might generate some extra methods that you might not (or might, again, depends on your usage) want. I remember having some problems with nested entities and cyclic dependencies with the generated `toString` method.

Comment: You can also drop the `@Configuration` if you enable the `ConfigurationProperties` explicitly via `EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)`

Comment: Thank you both of you. I like this solution, but it doesn't work in my case. Could you give me some hints, why can it be?